# Where can i find list of available colours for gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What are the list of gazebo material colour names which i can directly use with my robot? I have found its answer before this, but now i forgot/not finding in google where i exactly found those names, i should have saved them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15174/where-can-i-find-list-of-available-colours-for-gazebo/) by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are a few options for colors:

1. You can use any color by specifying its RGBA values in [SDF](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=material#material_ambient), for example:

   ```
     <material>
      <ambient>0.46 0.46 0.46 1.0</ambient>
      <diffuse>0.46 0.46 0.46 1.0</diffuse>
      <specular>0.46 0.46 0.46 1.0</specular>
      <emissive>0.46 0.46 0.46 1.0</emissive>
    </material>
   ```
2. You can refer to one of the ogre [materials](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/a1fb370811b64723827c4e40fa3867ccbd8fd584/media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material?fileviewer=file-view-default) which come defined with Gazebo:

   ```
    <material>
        <script>Gazebo/Orange</script>
    </material>
   ```
3. You can create your own ogre material as explained in [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=lightmap&cat=rendering) tutorial
4. If you want to use textures which are not uniformly placed on your model, you will need to create a COLLADA file (with Blender for example) which references the texture within it. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/f8f2f9af8a59da5f5c60416a29eecdfae5f90125/number1/?at=default)'s an example model, the COLLADA file goes in the `/meshes` directory and the texture goes in the `/materials/textures` directory. The COLLADA file must reference the texture within itself.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on 2017-01-06**:
from light map tutorilal i learned to put textures to a models, but if i want to put those textures in a way in which some name or some sign will also be visible in a specific position in model, than how can i do it? I used blender to put colors in model but the colour was not looking exact so i changed the colour sid value in its dae file, so it looked little good but not that much. is their any other way to do this.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-01-06**:
What you want to do is to play with texture coordinates. I added another item to the answer explaining that.

**Comment by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on 2017-01-07**:
ok. thanks. i'll see how to do that now.